# Eclipse unable to see NDK in the preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

Just now I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse ADT (23.0.2) To set the NDK path in Eclipse editor, I went to Window Preferences, when I choose Android, I am unable to see the NDK menu. Can anyone help me how to set NDK path in latest version of Eclipse

Comment: Have you looked at a tutorial like this first? http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html